# NLog- Can I create a static class that handles all logging without damaging performance or async operations?

Tags: nlog

I want to add the usage of NLog to my project and I think that it would be nice to have a static class that handles all logging. something like this:

```
public static class NLogger
{

public static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();


public static void Info(string message, object obj = null)
{
    string userId = "111111";
    string agentId = "666666";


    NLog.LogEventInfo info = new NLog.LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Info, logger.Name, message);
    info.Properties["UserId"] = userId;
    info.Properties["AgentId"] = agentId;

    logger.Log(info);
}

public static void Debug(string message, object obj = null)
{
    string userId = "111111";
    string agentId = "666666";


    NLog.LogEventInfo info = new NLog.LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, logger.Name, message);
    info.Properties["LoggedInUserId"] = userId;
    info.Properties["LoggedInAgetnID"] = agentId;

    logger.Log(info);
}
}
```

I know that NLog handles async writings and can handle multiple log requests at the same time.
Is wrapping NLog like the example above will damage its behavior?

Comment: Did you think about a dependency injection? Take also look to asp.net core 2.x.

Comment: You could consider check `logger.IsDebugEnabled` before allocating the LogEventInfo.